# Customize Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon in Dialog ONLY

Tags: 2010, ribbon, css, modal-dialog

In the screenshoot below I pasted the Dialog of the NEW ITEM on top of our website.

1. The ribbon bar selected in red, we want to change it, but it should be different to the ribbon bar in the normal site. I meant only customize it for the Dialog.

I found this website:
http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html

But apparently there is no CSS class for that element only.   It looks it uses the same elements than the normal site.

Is it possible, and how?  I need that RED area I selected to have the same color of the title bar, Discussion Board- New Item.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add .ms-dialog in front of the class you want to change, and it will only affect the modal dialogs:

```
.ms-dialog .ms-cui-topBar2{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: amazing!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: can you this one please?? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/tricky-error-in-dialogbox-styling