# Tricky error in dialogbox styling

Tags: 2010, ribbon, css

This question is related to this:
[Customize Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon in Dialog ONLY](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30594/customize-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-in-dialog-only)

I did what suggested there and it works fine, but with a small problem shown on the screenshot below.

My Ribbon html in the master page says:

```
<div class="ribbon-fixedwidth">
<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
    <div id="s4-ribboncont">
        <SharePoint:SPRibbon
            runat="server"
            PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer"  
            CssFile="">
            <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                runat="server"
                Location="TabRowLeft"
                CssClass="ms-siteactionscontainer s4-notdlg">
```

And I paste below also some css clases that I thought I should change, even though I changed the width of these classes, it didnt make any change in the result:

```
/* Ribbon Fixed width */
.ribbon-fixedwidth {
width:920px;
margin:auto;
-padding-right:17px;
}

#s4-titlerow {
width:980px !important;
margin:auto;
-padding-right:17px;
}

#OST-HorTopNav {
height:40px;
background-image: url("/_LAYOUTS/1033/IMAGES/MirageTeams/NEWSlice.gif");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
width:980px !important;
margin:auto;
-padding-right:17px;
}

.ms-dlgTitle {
background-color:#EFEFEF;   
}

.ms-dlgTitleText {
color:#003365 !important;
}
```

![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of tries for hours. it was a simple new css class.

.ms-dialog .ribbon-fixedwidth {
width:100%;
}

that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems some margin-story. It is difficult to say what is wrong exactly. Try to set the background-color of one of the parent elements (which defines background-color in corev4.css):

```
.ms-dialog body #s4-ribbonrow {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Or reset right and left margin of ".ms-dialog .ms-cui-topBar2" (probably this element)

```
.ms-dialog .ms-cui-topBar2 {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: didnt work, i have tried everything, its there a way you can help me further via email, skype? or whatever?

Comment: It was what I said, a margin story. I couldn't know the exact classes from your solution. Cool, that you found them (.ribbon-fixedwidth)